# Как получить названия столбцов из SQL запроса при импорте в Excel через VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Пишу макрос для выгрузки данных из БД прямо на лист.

```
Sub Load_longer_period()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    login = ...
    pass = ...
    conn.open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=" & pass & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & login & ";Data Source=..."

    conn.BeginTrans
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from test_table"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Договоры").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Но данный макрос выгружает результат без названия самих столбцов, только сами данные. Как получить ещё вдобавок и названия столбцов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблицу, которую получаем после выполнения запроса прогоняем в цикле, с помощью .Name получаем имена столбцов. Код примерно следующий.

```
Set rsResponses = cmdSQL.Execute('YourCode')
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsResponses

For i = 1 To rsResponses.fields.Count
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = rsResponses.fields(i).Name
Next i
```

Как альтернатива, в виде костыля :)
Запросом вытаскивайте названия столбцов.
А дальше либо UNION ALL к данным из основного запроса (нужно проверить на соответствие типов столбцов в запросе с названиями и данными), либо в макросе выполнять запрос отдельно и вставлять перед данными

```
select s.name from sys.columns s
join sys.tables x on s.object_id = x.object_id
where x.name = 'table_name'
```

Comment: Я думаю, это немного костыльное решение, но как запасное, если что сойдёт.

Comment: Нагуглилось, кажется предлагают более "прямое" решение http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/513138-copyfromrecordset-not-returning-column-headings-sql.html

Comment: Да, всё верно. Переместите код из ссылки в ответ, я отмечу как верный.

Answer (score 1):

> ... макрос выгружает результат без названия самих столбцов,
>   только сами данные. 
> Как получить ещё вдобавок и названия столбцов? ...

Используйте `QueryTable`, получите результат с названиями столбцов.

```
Sub Get_Dataset()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection: Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCon$, strSQL$, login$, pass$, QT As QueryTable

    login = "your login"
    pass = "your password" 

    strCon = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=" & pass & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & login & ";Data Source=..."

    strSQL = "select * from test_table"

    cn.Open strCon

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    With Sheets("Договоры")
    Set QT = .QueryTables.Add(rs, .[A1])
        QT.Refresh
        QT.Delete
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
    End With
End Sub
```